How can I remedy basement slab heave due to water pressure?
I have a finished basement with a storage room that has no flooring (just concrete)
There is a French drain, and all downspouts direct away from the house. I noticed some small heaving in this area pictured. It is clear that there is efflorescence as well. At this point what can I even do here? I can easily cut out a 4x4 section, dig down a bit and re-fill, but I dont know if that will solve it. Some of the basement slab is very thin due to the age of the house.


If you have a french drain and water is still accumulating under the slab enough to cause pressure, you can't fix this by resurfacing.  You need an engineer to figure out where the water is coming from, where it is going to, and how it can get there more easily.   If it's trickling up from beneath and has no way to get to the french drain, that's a problem you can solve.  Not easily, but you need to understand it first.

What's interesting is the section in the picture you can see an area I previously repaired, which hasn't heaved and is still flat.  The area that's cracking/rising up is along the seam where the repair meets the original floor. Wonder why that is.

Hate to be the bearer of bad news here, but I've found that trying to keep moisture contained with concrete or fillers is a fool's errand. I've owned a 1911 house in Seattle for years and fought this a ton with a slab that is not consistently 4". Yes, you could cut it out, clean and coat the edges with a sealant then pour a new 4" block in. However, that's a ton of work and will likely just end up looking like a more geometric version of what you have already.
In my situation, I ended up busting up about 1/3" of my slab, shaping the clay underneath to all slope towards a new sump pit then backfilled it with 2 yards of pea gravel before repouring 109 bags of concrete. Dramatic and a mountain of work but even on the wettest January day in Seattle, my floor is dry.
Like you've probably heard, water intrusion is always a function of what's happening outside and a project for there, not inside.
That efflorescence could have taken a decade to form so I wouldn't be too worried about it honestly unless it's visibly damp or moist. If your slab looks like this, my guess is that there are far more important things to be tending to on your house. Sand or grind it real good, slap some paint on there and just monitor it once a season.
Sorry I couldn't offer any relatively easy solutions!

The basement is finished, I just didn’t put a floor down here as this is a storage area. This was painted 3 years ago. Major demo of the existing slab is not an option.

Ok. Efflorescence in 3 years isn’t anything to worry about. Clean it and paint over it if you don’t want to look at it. I’d honestly just leave it :)
